# Añadir nueva propiedad al modelo sin utilizar Migraciones EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Es posible actualizar el modelo añadiendo una nueva columna a la base de datos sin utilizar migraciones? Ya que me ha parecido encontrar algunos tutoriales (pero no especifica como hacerlo), que modificando el schema de la base de datos y añadiendo la propiedad del modelo es posible actualizarlo, lo he intentado pero nada.

Answer (score 2):

Claro seguro puedes agregar los cambios mediente script o manualmente simpre que esta coincida con el mapping que realizas en entity framework.

[Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)

puedes trabajar EF con una base de datos existente, en este caso no se utiliza migrations, sino que tienes una estructura de datos existente que mapeas con las entidades en tu codigo

Si utilizas un edmx puede actualizar la db y luego usar la opcion "Update Model from Database"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es posible solo añadiendo el campo a la BD y actualizando el modelo nada mas? o se tiene que hacer con un proyecto code first from database?

Comment: o sea estas usando un edmx? como mencionaste migrations imagine mapeas usando code first

Comment: Sin utilizar un .edmx eso seria posible? yo estaba modificando en el shema de la base de datos no del .edmx(ya que no lo tengo).

Comment: actualice la respuesta con la opcion que usarias desde el edmx para actualizar el modelo

Comment: Pero se puede hacer sin .edmx?

Comment: pero estas usando DataBase First, se tiene que usar el modelado visual. Sino quieres el modelo quizas podrias editar el edmx como xml y agregar los tag que actualizan el mapping, pero lo veo algo complejo